# Zend/Apache mod_rewrite... what's wrong?

Tags: php, zend-framework, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The following url works ok:

```
http://localhost/index/index/
```

However, I am unable to _get$ variables when they come in like this:

http://localhost/index/index/test/1234/test2/4321

-but-

I can however, _get$ the variables these ways:

```
http://localhost/index.php?test=1234&test2=4321
http://localhost/index?test=1234&test2=4321
http://localhost/index/index?test=1234&test2=4321
```

Why does are the variables not showing up for me when I use the /index/index/var/val way?

Below you will find my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zend Framework doesn't make data in the request uri available as $_GET variables, to access them, use the key in a **controller**:

```
$test = $this->getRequest()->getParam('test') //$test = 1234
```

Or shorter

```
$test = $this->_getParam('test');
```

Comment: This is the answer... I guess I got offtrack, as I was using _GET$ with the Zend_Filter_Input.

Answer (score 0):

Because `$_GET` contains the variables in the query string - that's the part of the URL after the question mark. Notice that the rewriting rules in your `.htaccess` file turn *all* URLS that do not refer to existing files or directories into just `index.php`, without any trace of the original URL (though, as Gumbo's comment reminded me, it's still accessible via `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Your `RewriteRule`s don't create a query string (i.e. they don't put a question mark into the URL), which is what you'd need to do to use `$_GET`.

I would suggest replacing your last `RewriteRule` with something like

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php$0 [NC,L]
```

That `$0` will append the original URL to `index.php` - so for example, `http://localhost/index/index/test/1234/test2/4321` will become `http://localhost/index.php/index/index/test/1234/test2/4321` Then the request will be handled by `index.php` and the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` variable will be set to the original URL, `/index/index/test/1234/test2/4321`.  You can write some PHP code to parse that and pick out whatever parameters you want.

If you don't want the `/index/index` at the beginning to be saved in the path_info variable, you can use a `RewriteRule` like this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^/index/index(.*)$ index.php$1 [NC,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^(/index)*(.*)$ index.php$2 [NC,L]
```

to strip off any number of leading `/index`es.

*EDIT*: actually, you can keep your existing `RewriteRule`s and just look at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the original request URI; no messing around with the path info is needed. Then you can split that up as you like in PHP.

Comment: so what would I need to do to convert the rest of the query string to use slashes instead of ? and &'s ?

Comment: The original requested URL path and query is not lost (see $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).

Comment: seems my problem is with my lack of knowledge with Zend, rather than my lack of knowledge with mod_rewrite, lol.  Ty for the help though.

Comment: hm, well... I wrote my answer assuming you were using plain PHP, no frameworks.  Oops I guess :-/